# Unable to build rsyslog with static libz.a (zlib) file

Tags: unix, zlib, rsyslog, xlc

unable to build **rsyslog v8.2208.0** with static **libz.a** library in **aix 6.1**. libz.a contains object files. so there is no shared object file. while building i'm exporting ZLIB_LIBS to the directory where my libz archive file is present.

```
export ZLIB_LIBS="-L/opt/zlib/lib"
```

now while run **gmake** command to build rsyslog it's throwing below error and i'm using **xlc** compiler

```
CCLD     rsyslogd
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .uncompress
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .deflate
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .deflateEnd
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .deflateInit_
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .compress2
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:729: rsyslogd] Error 8
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/rsyslog_2208/rsyslog-8.2208.0/tools'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:913: all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/rsyslog_2208/rsyslog-8.2208.0'
gmake: *** [Makefile:761: all] Error 2
```

how should i build rsyslog with a static libz library?

Comment: To get more information, insert `V=1` into make-command: `gmake V=1 all`